# Access one specific object from class name?

Tags: static, swift

I want to access **a specific** object with the class name. This object may change, so it is **not** a singleton.

Like:

```
MyClass.actualView
```

or

```
MyClass.actualView()
```

Since I get `class var are not yet supported` as an error, any good short ways in your mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "access object with the class name"? There may be (and usually are) multiple instances of the same class…

Comment: As I said: One specific object, which I then set anywhere anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a global variable and a calculated type property. Only the constant type property are not supported yet.

```
private var globalVar: MyClass? = nil

class MyClass  {

    internal class var sharedInstance : MyClass {
        get {
            return globalVar
        set {
            globalVar = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Before using it, it must be set from any of the instances:

```
MyClass.sharedInstance = self
```

Now I could set and get the type property like I could in every other language, until Apple makes it easier and supports constant type properties.
I can get the sharedInstance from anywhere inside the project (even accessible from Objective-C, when you add `@objc` before the `internal`-keyword

#### Swift:

```
MyClass.sharedInstance
```

#### Objective-C:

```
[MyClass sharedInstance];
```